# Recover the reprojection error from Levenberg Marquardt iteration OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, optimization, camera, calibration

I'm working currently on Camera Calibration using OpenCV C++ library which seems to be very good.
As it is mentionned in [openCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga3207604e4b1a1758aa66acb6ed5aa65d), the calibrateCamera runs LM optimization to minimize the reprojection error by refining the homography. I understand the theory, however, I must recover the data calculated at each LM iteration to plot the evolution of reprojection error at each iteration, and I really cannot see how to do that, [here is a figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOwoh.png) that shows an example, I am aiming at the residuals just like in figure a  (found only by searching on google).

Answer (score 0):

If you want information out an OpenCV API that it's not designed to give (here, reprojection error for every iteration), you will have to change OpenCV code and recompile the library.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so which part of the library should be modified ?

Comment: documentation says your targeted function resides in the calib3d module